# Em Python, existe alguma regra ou vantagem quanto ao uso do 'Self'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Consideremos os exemplos abaixo:

Exemplo 1:

```
> class PrintText():
>     def __init__(self):
>         text = 'Funciona!'
>         self.printa(text)
>         
>     def printa(self, text):
>         print(text)
```

Exemplo 2:

```
> class PrintText():
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.text = 'Funciona!'
>         self.printa()
>         
>     def printa(self):
>         print(self.text)
```

Vamos supor que na classe PrintText existem vários casos como esse, onde determinada variável é usada por apenas uma ou duas funções; É melhor usar o Exemplo 1 que passa a variável como argumento para a função, ou usar o Exemplo 2 que declara explicitamente o 'self'?
Os dois exemplos funcionam, mas existe uma vantagem entre um ou outro, ou um deles está incorreto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Então - as duas formas funcionam - o que é feito  no primeiro exemplo é que, mesmo se tratando da chamada de um método de classe, o parâmetro é passado explicitamente - ou seja - a função "printa" poderia ser uma função normal do Python, e não um método da mesma classe, que cumpriria o mesmo papel.

Já da segunda forma, o valor de "text" é anotado como um atributo do objeto - e o método é chamado sem nenhum parâmetro explícito - ele usa o atributo do "text" do objeto.

Na prática, a primeira abordagem é típica de um desenho de aplicação estruturado. Mesmo usando a classe, e objetos, o "tipo de raciocínio" que se usa quando os parâmetros são passados explicitamente é o estruturado.

Em contraste, agrupar dados e funções que vão trabalhar com esses dados (os métodos) num mesmo objeto, é a própria fundação do pensamento "Orientado a Objeto". Um dos grandes ganhos de uma programação orientada a objetos é justamente não ter que se passar todos os parâmetros que representam o estado daquele objeto como parâmetros para os métodos: os métodos tem acesso a esses valores na forma de atributos.

No seu exemplo você está usando um único atributo. Mas um objeto complexo poderia ter dezenas de atributos distintos - um personagem de um jogo, por exemplo, tem que ter como parâmetros as coordenadas no mapa, uma referência ao próprio objeto mapa, quanto tem de energia, velocidade, se está na posse de algum item (e quais), e, para ser efetivamente desenhado na tela, ainda tem que ter referência as imagens em si que serão usadas para desenhá-lo, posição na tela, e assim por diante - usando a abordagem estruturada, essas dezenas de parâmetros teriam que ser passadas em várias chamadas de função para tratar do mesmo objeto.

Perceba que se alguém está usando uma estrutura de dados que agrupa os parâmetros relacionados a um item - esse personagem de jogo, por exemplo, e passa essa estrutura como parâmetro para todas as funções que vão lidar com o personagem, está acontecendo o contrário do que acontece no seu primeiro exemplo: usando-se uma programação estruturada na forma, mas na prática é orientada a objeto.

Essa é a parte conceitual. Falando em detalhes mais técnicos, e específicos do Python - no seu primeiro exemplo, o valor de "text" é acessível com esse nome no método `__init__` como uma variável local, e de novo como uma variável local na função `printa`. Já no segundo exemplo, a variável local que é usada nos dois métodos é o `self` - o valor de `text` fica armazenado num "variável do objeto" - ou seja, dentro do dicionário `__dict__` do objeto `self`. Faça um teste, e mande imprimir `self.__dict__["text"]`. Dessa forma ele é visível e acessível para qualquer um que tiver acesso ao objeto - no conceito de  OO, é um atributo "público". Já na primeira forma, nenhuma função de fora do objeto, e nem outros métodos do objeto, podem acessar o valor de `self`.

Comment: Muito bem respondido, obrigado! Mas ainda me resta uma dúvida: Desconsiderando situações em que não queremos deixar a variável acessível a 'todos', existe alguma situação em que o uso do 'self' pode ser considerada uma má pratica, existe uso indiscriminado do self?

Comment: Se você está com um design orientadoa  objetos e usando classes em seu programa, melhor usar o self. Entretanto Python permite uqe uma aplicação seja desenhada de forma estruturada ou funcional  - daí não se usa o self de qualquer forma. O "jeito de pensar" nos problemas com as duas abordagens muda.

Answer (score 2):

Olá. Ambos os exemplos estão corretos mas é mais vulgar a utilização do self do exemplo 2.
Exemplo do uso do self:

```
class Animal(object):
is_alive = True
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
# Add your method here!
def description(self):
    print self.name
    print self.age
```

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Poderia me esclarecer melhor a ideia que quis passar com 'vulgar'? Não entendi se devo levar ao pé da letra ou se quis dizer vulgar no sentido de 'mais usado'.

Comment: No sentido de mais usado.

Comment: @Henrique só uma nota: sugiro que quando for colocar snippets os usem em português. Não que acredito estar errado, mas acho que fica mais fácil para os usuários do site entender `esta_vivo` a  `is_alive` por exemplo.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun, Obrigado pela dica :)