# GPing deve ser chamado como primeiro argumento

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
top_100_domains = ['google.com','facebook.com','youtube.com','yahoo.com','baidu.com','wikipedia.org','live.com','qq.com','twitter.com','amazon.com','linkedin.com','blogspot.com','google.co.in','taobao.com','sina.com.cn','yahoo.co.jp','msn.com','google.com.hk','wordpress.com','google.de','google.co.jp','google.co.uk','ebay.com','yandex.ru','163.com','google.fr','weibo.com','googleusercontent.com','bing.com','microsoft.com','google.com.br','babylon.com','soso.com','apple.com','mail.ru','t.co','tumblr.com','vk.com','google.ru','sohu.com','google.es','pinterest.com','google.it','craigslist.org','bbc.co.uk','livejasmin.com','tudou.com','paypal.com','blogger.com','xhamster.com','ask.com','youku.com','fc2.com','google.com.mx','xvideos.com','google.ca','imdb.com','flickr.com','go.com','tmall.com','avg.com','ifeng.com','hao123.com','zedo.com','conduit.com','google.co.id','pornhub.com','adobe.com','blogspot.in','odnoklassniki.ru','google.com.tr','cnn.com','aol.com','360buy.com','google.com.au','rakuten.co.jp','about.com','mediafire.com','alibaba.com','ebay.de','espn.go.com','wordpress.org','chinaz.com','google.pl','stackoverflow.com','netflix.com','ebay.co.uk','uol.com.br','amazon.de','ameblo.jp','adf.ly','godaddy.com','huffingtonpost.com','amazon.co.jp','cnet.com','globo.com','youporn.com','4shared.com','thepiratebay.se','renren.com']
gp = GPing
for domain in top_100_domains:
    gp.send(domain,test_callback)
gp.join()
```

ERRO:

> gp.send(domain,test_callback)
>   TypeError: unbound method send() must be called with GPing instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: Está usando Python 3 ou Python 2? Tente usar assim `gp = GPing()`

Comment: Estou usando o 2, coloquei o parentêses e apresenta outro erro, anteriormente estava com e tirei para tentar resolver.

Comment: E qual seria este tal outro erro?

Comment: raise socket.error(msg)
socket.error: Operation not permitted - Note that ICMP messages can only be sent from processes running as root.

Comment: Yúlia tente rodar como root, se for Debian ou Ubuntu tente `sudo`

Comment: Vou tentar!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro acontece porque você está chamando o método de forma estática, sem instanciar a classe. Ao fazer:

```
gp = GPing
```

Você não está criando uma instância da classe, mas sim passando a referência da classe a outro objeto. Para corrigir, basta inserir os parenteses:

```
gp = GPing()
```

Pode verificar isso exibindo o objeto `gp`.

```
>>> gp = GPing
>>> print(gp)
<class 'GPing'>
```

Mas ao fazer:

```
>>> gp = GPing()
>>> print(gp)
<GPing object at 0x...>
```

Perceba que na primeira maneira, `gp` faz referência à classe `GPing` enquanto na segunda faz referência ao `object` da mesma classe.

O erro em si acontece por que o método `send` deve ser definido como:

```
def send(self, domain, callback):
    ...
```

Em que `self` é a própria instância da classe `GPing`. Chamar o método sem criar a instância, o primeiro argumento do método não é definido automaticamente e, portanto, gera-se um erro de tipo.

**Perguntas relacionadas**

[Por que temos que utilizar o atributo self como argumento nos métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176543/por-que-temos-que-utilizar-o-atributo-self-como-argumento-nos-m%C3%A9todos)

[Em Python, existe alguma regra ou vantagem quanto ao uso do 'Self'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23913/em-python-existe-alguma-regra-ou-vantagem-quanto-ao-uso-do-self)

[Como chamar uma função externa, sem enviar o 'self'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1507/como-chamar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-externa-sem-enviar-o-self)

Comment: Foi [mais rápido do que eu](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194319/gping-deve-ser-chamado-como-primeiro-argumento#comment400818_194319), eu imaginei que era isto mesmo, mas sendo Python2 eu fiquei sem ter certeza, eu uso o 3. +1

Comment: Já sinalizei como erro de digitação também, mas resolvi responder porque acho que algumas linguagens permitem a instância sem utilizar os parenteses.

Comment: Acho que ela está com outro problema :/ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194319/gping-deve-ser-chamado-como-primeiro-argumento?noredirect=1#comment400823_194319